# Html.ActionLink reference error MVC4 in Areas

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

I've created an Area in my app called "Admin" and when I attempt to use @html.actionlink() to build some menu items I'm met with a reference error.

> system.web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper does not contain a definition for ActionLink and the best extension method overload System.Web.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink(System.Web.HtmlHelper,string,  string, string) has some invalid arguments.

This is the line of code that's generating the error.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Posts", "Index", new { area = "admin" });
```

I've googled around and attempted adding `using system.web.mvc.html;` with no benefit or change in behavior.  I've checked the web.config file for the area and confirmed that both `system.web.mvc` and `system.web.mvc.html` are included in the namespaces, also to no avail.

Comment: Do you have a `web.config` in `/Areas/Admin/Views`?

Comment: DavidG. I do. I checked it and the proper namespaces are all there.

Comment: I vaguely remember encountering this problem. Try restarting studio. I seem to remember there being an SO post with that little tidbit, and that's what did the trick for me (stupid I know).

Comment: Thanks mike. I'll check that.

Comment: Check that you're using the correct overload for [HtmlHelper.ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You are using actionlink wrongly.

Below is the correct usage of actionlink(i m taking example of any arbitrary actionlink)

```
Html.ActionLink(article.Title,   // <--Link Text
            "Item",   // <-- ActionMethod
            "Login",  // <-- Controller Name.
            new { id = article.ArticleID }, // <-- Route arguments.
            null  // <-- htmlArguments 
            )
```

This uses the following method ActionLink signature:

```
public static string ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
                            string linkText,
                            string actionName,
                            string controllerName,
                            object values, 
                            object htmlAttributes)
```

**The error is coming in your question because 3rd overload of Actionlink is controller name.**

```
@Html.ActionLink("// Link Text //", "// Action Name //",// controller name //, new { area = "admin" });
```

Comment: I believe the option he is using is Controller, Action, Options.  So Posts is his controller name

Comment: Correct. Posts is the controller. Action is index

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `web.config` in your `/Areas/Admin/Views` folder. Just create the basic one like below, the key part being the added namespaces:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="Club.Web" />
        <add namespace="Club.Web.Helpers"/>

      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I have a web.config and it accounts for mvc.html and the others. Am I missing something?